# Overriding a single interface method when the implementing class is sealed

Tags: c#, interface, sealed

This is probably easiest to explain with code (this is of course not the actual code but it has the same properties):

I have an interface that looks something like this:

```
    public interface ISomeProvider
    {
        object GetFoo1(); //<-- This needs caching

        //These others don't
        object GetFoo2();
        object GetFoo3();

        //And let's say 20 more
    }
```

And this has an implementation like this:

```
    //NOTE: Sealed class otherwise we could inherit from it
    public sealed  class SuperCleverProvider : ISomeProvider
    {
        public object GetFoo1()
        {
            return "a";
        }

        public object GetFoo2()
        {
            return "b";
        }

        public object GetFoo3()
        {
            return "b";
        }
    }
```

Now one of these calls, let's say GetFoo1 is really heavy so I want to provider a new version of the interface where calls to it are cached using an instance of the old one.

I'm doing it like this at the moment:

```
    public class CachedSuperCleverProvider : ISomeProvider
    {
        private readonly SuperCleverProvider _provider;

        public CachedSuperCleverProvider(SuperCleverProvider provider)
        {
            _provider = provider;
        }

        private object UsingCache<T>(string cacheKey, Func<T> eval)
        {
            //Pretend this does caching. This is not related to the question
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public object GetFoo1()
        {
            return UsingCache("foo1", _provider.GetFoo1);
        }

        //The code below this point is what I want to get rid of
        public object GetFoo2()
        {
            return _provider.GetFoo2();
        }

        public object GetFoo3()
        {
            return _provider.GetFoo3();
        }

        //And so on for all the rest
    }
```

This has two problems (at least):

- Every time someone adds a method to the interface I have to go change this even though I dont want this new method to be cached
- I get this huge list of useless code that just call through to the underlying implementation.

Can anyone think of a way of doing this that doesn't have these problems?

Comment: Your way of doing it is 100% correct - it's inheritance through encapsulation. It's a mission to maintain, but your compiler will inform you if one of these classes is out of date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three options:

- Autogenerate the class
- Use [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp/features) or something similar to do it in a more interceptor-based way
- Live with it

Personally I'd probably go with the third option, unless you *really* find yourself doing this a lot. Weigh up the cost of each option - how much time are you *actually* going to spend adding this delegation?

Personally I'd *like* to see this sort of thing as a language feature - "delegate to this interface via this field unless I override it" but obviously that's not present at the moment...

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'd suggest.  It's not too much better, but will simplify the wrapping process.

Create a class `SomeProviderWrapper`:

```
public class SomeProviderWrapper : ISomeProvider
{
    protected ISomeProvider WrappedProvider { get; private set; }

    protected SomeProviderWrapper(ISomeProvider wrapped)
    {
        if (wrapped == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("wrapped");

        WrappedProvider = wrapped;
    }

    public virtual object GetFoo1()
    {
        return WrappedProvider.GetFoo1();
    }

    public virtual object GetFoo2()
    {
        return WrappedProvider.GetFoo2();
    }

    public virtual object GetFoo3()
    {
        return WrappedProvider.GetFoo3();
    }
}
```

Now that the wrapping is relegated to its own class, you can write the caching version:

```
public class CachedSuperCleverProvider : SomeProviderWrapper
{
    public CachedSuperCleverProvider(ISomeProvider wrapped) : base(wrapped) { }

    private object UsingCache<T>(string cacheKey, Func<T> eval)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object GetFoo1()
    {
        return UsingCache("foo1", WrappedProvider.GetFoo1);
    }
}
```

This keeps the delegation code out of your super clever provider.  You will still have to maintain the delegation code, but it won't pollute the design of your caching provider.